# tensorflow object detection API: training is very slow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am currently studying google [tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). When I try to retrain the model with Oxford III pet dataset, the training process is very slow.

Here is what I found so far:

1. most of time only 2% GPU is utilzed.
2. but CPU utilization is  60%, so It seems GPU is not starved by input, otherwise CPU should be near 100% utilization.

I am trying to profile it with tensorflow profiler, but I am in a bit hurry now, any idea or suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problems. It's the issue with input, my tfrecord file is corrupted somehow, so the input thread hang up sometimes.

Comment: How to check whether a tfrecord is corrupted or not?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this to happen. The most common being that there is some problem with your `record` file. There need to be done some testing before adding an image and it's contour to record file. Some of them are:

First check the image before sending it to the record:

```
def checkJPG(fn):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        try:
            image_contents = tf.read_file(fn)
            image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)
            init_op = tf.initialize_all_tables()
            with tf.Session() as sess:
                sess.run(init_op)
                tmp = sess.run(image)
        except:
            print("Corrupted file: ", fn)
            return False
    return True
```

Also, check the height and width of the contour and if any contour is not crossing the borders:

```
boxW = xmax - xmin
boxH = ymax - ymin
if boxW == 0 or boxH == 0:
    print("...ONE CONTOUR SKIPPED... (boxW | boxH) = 0")
    continue

if boxW*boxH < 100:
    print("...ONE CONTOUR SKIPPED... (boxW*boxH) < 100")
    continue

if xmin / width <= 0 or xmax / width <= 0 or ymin / height <= 0 or ymax / height <= 0:
    print("...ONE CONTOUR SKIPPED... (x | y) <= 0")
    continue
if xmin / width >= 1 or xmax / width >= 1 or ymin / height >= 1 or ymax / height >= 1:
    print("...ONE CONTOUR SKIPPED... (x | y) >= 1")
    continue
```

One of the other reason is that there is too much data in evaluation `record` file. It's better to add only 10 images in your evaluation record file and change the evaluation config like this:

```
eval_config {
  num_visualizations: 10
  num_examples: 10
  eval_interval_secs: 3000
  max_evals: 1
  use_moving_averages: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see , it is not utilizing GPU as now, 
Have you tried to optimise GPU using tensorflow given parameter

https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_gpu